# Group send kafka message and DB update in one Transaction in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I need to perform several operations in one transaction

- produce kafka message
- update Table A
- update Table B

I'm fine with sending message and don't update both tables (A and B). I'm not ok to produce message and update one of tables.

I'm trying to achieve my goal using `@Transactional` annotation

```java
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Isolation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

 @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
    public void handle(Event approvalEvent) {
        var entity = entityService.getLatestVersion(approvalEvent.getTransactionId());

        entityService.approve(entity.getTransactionId());
        logService.logApproval(entity);
        producer.send(approvalEvent);
    }
```

do I do it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the approach above that you are interacting with two distinct systems (Database and Message queue) in one transaction. The combinations of scenarios to handle when operation on one system is successful and fails in other system makes the solution complex.

There is pattern in the microservices world to handle the exact same scenario. It is called outbox pattern.

You can read more about it [here](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transactional-outbox.html).

The short summary is you have an additional table in your database called outbox that contains the messages that are to be published to the message queue.

In the DB transaction for adding\updating the entity you insert a row in the outbox table tool containing the details of operation on the entity.

Then you asynchronously read the rows from outbox table and publish to message queue either via poling or using change data capture. See a sample implementation [here](https://debezium.io/blog/2019/02/19/reliable-microservices-data-exchange-with-the-outbox-pattern/) using debezium.

Your transaction code would look like this.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public void handle(Event approvalEvent) {
    var entity = entityService.getLatestVersion(approvalEvent.getTransactionId());

    entityService.approve(entity.getTransactionId());
    logService.logApproval(entity);
    //Outbox is the table containing the records to be published to MQ 
    outboxRepo.save(approvalEvent);
}
```

Comment: I don't really follow why `outbox pattern` has advantage. My solution is idempotent and horizontally scalable. The only thing I need: rollback two DB transactions if kafka producer raises exception. And I can repeat transaction until kafka goes back online.

outbox pattern has the same issue: read and update DB, send to queue. #2 https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transactional-outbox.html would be really hard to scale out w/o redundant DB overload.

Comment: The point is you are keeping other third parties who are interested in the event decoupled from your event update/insert transaction. Assuming if you need to do some auditing and/or logging to log service you cannot be adding all that to your transaction method. This are all independent and asynchronous actions and should not affect/delay the the DB transaction.

Comment: debezium looks really promising. Thanks, I'll check it!